# How to use Consul Watches on an agent running on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, watch, consul

I've a series of APIs (services) running in multiple machines (agents) and those services have some sort of health checks. I wanted to implement a watch that would trigger a notification every time a service status changes.
After reading Consul documentation, this is how it should look like:

```
consul watch -type=checks -service=myservice handler_script.ps1
```

My problem is with the handler. I've written a small PowerShell script that outputs to the script the JSON every time a change happens. But when I run the script, a notepad windows is opened with the content of the PowerShell script.
My questions is:

- What am I doing wrong?

And as a bonus question is: can I do this programmatically? At service registration, for example.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.automatedops.com/blog/2015/06/01/monitoring-with-powershell-and-consul/

Comment: Hi @DavidBrabant. I alreday have the checks in place (and one of them looks exactly like that). What I need is at the article referred by that one (https://www.vividcortex.com/blog/2015/05/22/consul-for-cluster-health-monitoring/). In that article there'a an Watch doing something similar to what I want (although it's in bash script) but I don't know how or where to set the Watch.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that consul doesn't know how to run .ps1 files. Try `cmd /c powershell.exe handler_script.ps1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To combine with Marks answer:

```
consul watch -type=service -service=myservice "cmd /c powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProilfe -File C:\\Workspace\\consul\\handler_script.ps1"
```

If you try to use config file, for consul version before 1.0, I used:

```
{
  "watches": 
  [
    {
        "type": "service",
        "service": "myservice",
        "handler": "cmd /c powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProilfe -File C:\\Workspace\\consul\\handler_script.ps1"
    }
  ]
}
```

For consul version above 1.0, I used:

```
{
  "watches": 
  [
    {
        "type": "checks",
        "handler_type": "script",
        "args": ["cmd", "/c", "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -File C:\\Workspace\\consul\\handler_script.ps1"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** change `-type=checks` to `-type=service`, also escape the absolute-path, ie, `C:\\handler_script.ps1`